# Deploying a list with custom InfoPath forms included in Sharepoint-hosted app

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, infopath, sharepoint-apps

I created a list and added some custom InfoPath forms to it. Is there any way to include the list and the forms in Sharepoint-hosted app? I was thinking about saving it as a .stp template and then deploying it but I don't really know how to do it. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is no way to do this. Even if you succeed with deploying the form in app, you won't be able to open it in the browser - probably SharePoint Apps don't support InfoPath browser forms.
Also, there is no way of deploying a .stp template in your app, as you cannot write any code.